# toolkitscriptmanager.cs not found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I apologize for putting up another one of these but I've tried all the methods for getting the AjaxControlToolkit working, I've tried the method for adding this to the web.config

```
<pages>
  <controls>
      <add tagPrefix="asp"
                 namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"
                 assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

But it then keeps saying that I can only have one instance of the scriptmanager(I made sure it to delete

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

). 
However I still get the same error. I've tried it just have in

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

But then it says it can't find toolkitscriptmanager.cs. Does anyone know whats going on. I'm doing this in a ASP.NET webform.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, in that there is a scriptmanager in the master page which if you put this in the web.config.

```
<pages>
 <controls>
  <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
 </controls>
</pages>
```

It will tell you, you have 2 instances of a script manager. Therefore you ave to modify the scriptmanager in the masterfile to:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server">
<Scripts>
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
</Scripts>
```

This should stop the error.